# AndEngine: Black screen when using LayoutGameActivity

Tags: android, andengine

I used to use SimpleBaseGameActivity for my app and everything was ok, but now I want to add some ads into the app, so I tried to use LayoutGameActivity. But I get the render view is completely black and I don't know why. That's my code:

```
public class AcGame extends LayoutGameActivity {
    [...]
    @Override
    protected int getLayoutID() {
        return R.layout.ad;
    }

    @Override
    protected int getRenderSurfaceViewID() {
        return R.id.layout_render;
    }

    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        [...]
        return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_FIXED, resolution, camera);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateResources(OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback) throws Exception {
        createResources();
        pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback) throws Exception {
        pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(createScene());
    }

    @Override
    public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene, OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) throws Exception {
        pOnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished();
    }
```

And that's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:id="@+id/layout_ad"
            >
        <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Ad Sample"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <org.andengine.opengl.view.RenderSurfaceView
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/layout_render"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

When I'm trying to debug, I can see that EngineOptions are creating, but no one of the LayoutGameActivity's methods was called (`onCreateResources`, `onCreateScene` or `onPopulateScene`). Can someone tell me what I've missed?

**UPD:** I've found that if to move button in xml down, scene is showing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <org.andengine.opengl.view.RenderSurfaceView
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/layout_render"
            />
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:id="@+id/layout_ad"
            >
        <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Ad Sample"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

But now I can't see my button and all seems like I'm still using SimpleBaseGameActivity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the solution: If you want to use `(Simple)LayoutGameActivity`, you have to use `RelativeLayout`.
Also if you use `LayoutGameActivity` instead of `SimpleLayoutGameActivity`, don't forget to use callbacks!